# How to force programs in /usr/bin to always use libs in /usr/lib

Tags: linux, fedora, dynamic-linking

I'm struggling with a path problem on Fedora 26. I am building updated programs and libraries and placing them at `/usr/local`. Programs in `/usr/local/bin` use the libraries in `/usr/local/lib`. For some reason that's unknown at the moment, Fedora 26's `gawk`, which is located in `/usr/bin/gawk`, is using a library at `/usr/local/lib`.

The library in `/usr/local/lib` not compatible with the one `gawk` expects, so its breaking my scripts. Or more correctly, my script calls Autotools, and then Autotools breaks even though paths are not messed with. More information on the background problem is available at [libreadline.so.7: undefined symbol: UP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46881581/608639) on Stack Overflow.

I would like to enforce a policy which says, any program in `/usr/bin` must link to libraries in `/usr/lib`. I don't care about swizzling or inter-positioning. If I need to do it, then I'll build the package from sources and install it into `/usr/local`.

Other OSes solved this problem long ago with things like `install_names` on OS X and manifests on Windows. Linux just allows the same problems to fester (I think `--enable-new-dtags` is the latest band-aide that does not fix the problem).

How do I force the programs in `/usr/bin` to link to libraries in `/usr/lib`?

Comment: Are you setting this with LD_PRELOAD? Have you modified ld.so.conf?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the search path in the executable by specifying a  `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic section. See [the ld.so man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). Using the standard location in `/usr/lib` should be the norm, and the (hopefully not too many) programs you want to use your `/usr/local/lib` libraries should be linked by adding the following gcc options for the linker:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-tags ...
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I add the section to Fedora's `gawk` in `/usr/bin`? It seems easier to apply a system-wide policy of "if the program originates in `/usr/bin`, then it can only link to libraries in `/usr/lib`. But I'm will to use something like `editelf` to add the section since to `gawk` since the dynamic linker cannot get things right.

Comment: If you search on the web, you'll find some utilities that can be used. For example, `patchelf`. DT_RPATH and DT_RUNPATH do the same thing, but DT_RPATH has been deprecated in favor of DT_RUNPATH which is searched after LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
```

or directly run the command as:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib gawk
```

You can configure the default search order in `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Comment: Thanks. If I am parsing things correctly, this does not seem to scale and casts an overly broad net. It does not scale because I'm not sure how to apply it to all aspects of the system, and not just the stuff launched from one of my terminals. Its overly broad because it applies to more than the binaries in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

When manually compiling libraries that already are present in the system, no matter where they go `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/lib64`, the newest installation takes precedence. The library path is specified in /etc/ld.so.conf which in turn reads files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. You can create a new file there with the path to any library you want and then run `ldconfig` when you're done.

Alternatively, in your script, you can set your own paths to libraries using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. This will force the script to take whatever library paths are specified there. Multiple paths can be provided delimited by semicolons.

Comment: Thanks. How do I tell `ld.so` that any program in `/usr/bin` must link to libraries in `/usr/lib`? Is there even a way to do it? (I also think the answer suffers similar issues as Ipor's answer).

Comment: The locations /usr/lib and the like are used for shared libraries, so no, you cannot specify that all /bin binaries should use libraries from /usr/lib only. All binaires compiled to use shared libraries will look for the libraries in the shared libraries paths specified in ld.so.conf. Instead, I woul recompile the program that's produced the /usr/local/lib library, the one that's messing up gawk, with static libraries. This way you will force that program alone to use the newly compiled library, which will not be used by any other program. Just compile that library as static, instead of shared